# mouseover, mouseout not working well across windows

Tags: javascript, html

This problem is a little complicated and wordy.

I have a parent window, which pops out a child window. They have some overlapping area.
In parent window, there is a div which handles mouseover and mouseout event.
When the child window pops out, it covers part of the parent div.

In the following, mouse moves to div (mouseover works), click pops out child window. 
Now move mouse to child window. At this moment, I expect mouseout to div, but not.
I guess the system still thinks the mouse is within div even covered by the child window.

Is there any way to get through this? But the relative position of those elements should not change. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: The `event.stopPropagation` or `event.stopImediatePropagation` should do the work. This way you will tell the event handler to do not propagate on the chaining route up to the parent element, only apply to the child element. This way when you mouse over to the child element the event won't bobble up on the node structure, but will stay on the active element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all else fails move your code from the mouseout event of the div to the mouseover event of the pop-up. First, though, I'd make sure that the mouseout event ever fires, e.g. when you move outside the div's bounds.

Comment: mouseout works. I just want to correct my previous observation: once mouse moves from parent to child window, the parent window no longer receives mouseout.

Comment: Update: This seems to be related to different (maybe older) version of Firefox.